# GPS Android

Tags: android, gps

В программе хочу получить текущие координаты. Выполняю:

```
public void DeterminThePosition() {  
loc = getLastCopords();  
String str = "" + loc.getLongitude();  
String str2 = "" + loc.getLatitude();}
```

Соответственно есть функции:

```
private Location getLastCopords() {  
String[] providers = new String[] { LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,  
                                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,  
                LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER};  
        Location loc = null;  
        for (String provider : providers) {  
            loc = myGPS.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            if (loc != null) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return loc;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

В глобальных описываю: 
LocationManager myGPS;
    Location loc;

В onCreate:
myGPS = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

Раньше все работало прекрасно. Но после определенного запуска перестало работать все. Сваливается на моменте, когда обращаюсь к loc, т.к. loc = 0;
В чем может быть проблема?
    Логи:

```
10-04 23:03:30.715: E/AndroidRuntime(22374): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-04 23:03:30.715: E/AndroidRuntime(22374): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=tag1, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.map_1/com.example.map_1.MainA}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-04 23:03:30.715: E/AndroidRuntime(22374):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2997)
10-04 23:03:30.715: E/AndroidRuntime(22374):    at    android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3040)
10-04 23:03:30.715: E/AndroidRuntime(22374):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:128)
10-04 23:03:30.715: E/AndroidRuntime(22374):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1191)
10-04 23:03:30.715: E/AndroidRuntime(22374):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-04 23:03:30.715: E/AndroidRuntime(22374):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-04 23:03:30.715: E/AndroidRuntime(22374):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
10-04 23:03:30.715: E/AndroidRuntime(22374):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-04 23:03:30.715: E/AndroidRuntime(22374):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-04 23:03:30.715: E/AndroidRuntime(22374):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
10-04 23:03:30.715: E/AndroidRuntime(22374):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
10-04 23:03:30.715: E/AndroidRuntime(22374):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-04 23:03:30.715: E/AndroidRuntime(22374): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-04 23:03:30.715: E/AndroidRuntime(22374):    at com.example.map_1.OneActivity.DeterminThePosition(OneActivity.java:635)
10-04 23:03:30.715: E/AndroidRuntime(22374):    at com.example.map_1.OneActivity.RunningQuery(OneActivity.java:366)
10-04 23:03:30.715: E/AndroidRuntime(22374):    at com.example.map_1.OneActivity.onActivityResult(OneActivity.java:342)
10-04 23:03:30.715: E/AndroidRuntime(22374):    at android.app.ActivityGroup.dispatchActivityResult(ActivityGroup.java:122)
10-04 23:03:30.715: E/AndroidRuntime(22374):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2993)
10-04 23:03:30.715: E/AndroidRuntime(22374):    ... 11 more
10-04 23:03:40.345: I/Process(22374): Sending signal. PID: 22374 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Документацию читали? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation(java.lang.String)

> If the provider is currently disabled, null is returned.

Comment: на чем тестируешь? Выложи логи

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, Ну не может же быть, что ВСЕ недоступно, wifi подключен к интернету, сеть доступна.

Comment: @Gorets, на galaxy S3. Логи дописала в вопрос.

Comment: Если не было опроса местоположения, то будет null. Используемый вами метод с большой долей вероятности будет врать. Нужно подключать locationlistener и брать в нем координаты полученные как только так сразу.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, спасибо за совет. попробую..

Answer (score 1):

в манифесте проверь разрешение. может откатился неудачно и прочее..

Comment: @rn3kk, в манифесте все хорошо. в общем, получается так, что только по спутникам определяет.. а через сеть не определяет....